# How to play a transparent Video in Android?

Tags: android, video, transparent, alpha

I have a video with a transparent background that I want to use in my Android project.
I found [this library](https://github.com/pavelsemak/alpha-movie) but it's too old and the performance is not so good.
How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score -1):

You can use videoview like this;

```
 <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/video_background"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation_bar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

in your activity;

```
videoBackgroundView = findViewById(R.id.video_background)
val path = "android.resource://com.example.xxxxx" + "/" + R.raw.video
videoBackgroundView?.setVideoPath(path)
videoBackgroundView?.setOnPreparedListener { mp ->
    mp.isLooping = true
    videoBackgroundView?.start()
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work for me.still have a black screen as it's background

Comment: Post an answer only if you have read the question properly.